# Highligh a cell in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax

i have a dropdownlist with two values status- 'pending' and 'completed'. while im entering a new task my status is 'pending' once i finish it off i ll change my status as 'completed'. i have displayed it in gridview. the cell which i update as 'completed' have to be highlighted and the remaining cells in the status column i.e 'pending' has to be in another color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a serverside callback is possible in this scenario, then subscribe the OnRowDataBound-Event and look for the specific row and set the css class of a label to something different. You could use a TemplateColumn with a Label in it.

E.g.

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
  if(e.Row.RowType == RowType.DataRow)  
  {  
    YourObject _item = (YourObject)e.Row.DataItem;
    Literal _litFromTemplate = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("litFromTemplate");
    if(_item.Equals(anotherItem))  // or check for any other condition, like _item.Foo == 123
    {  
      _litFromTemplate.CssClass = 'highlightingMe';  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      _litFromTemplate.CssClass = 'normalcssclass';  
     }  
   }  
}
```